# Nested dynamic routing getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to create dynamic routes for a sitemap in the format `[type]/sitemap-[type].xml.js`.

As far as I understand from next's docs, the template paths (`[type]/[type].js`) will be populated by the props you export from `getServerSideProps`.

However, neither concatenating a string with a template (`sitemap-[type].js`), nor exporting a separate prop from `getServerSideProps` will work (see code below).

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const {
    res,
    query: { type },
  } = context;

  ...

  return {
    props: {
      type,
      slug: `sitemap-${type}`,
    },
  };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is `getServerSideProps` capable of nested dynamic routing for xml files altogether?

Comment: Next.js doesn't support dynamic paths like `[type]/sitemap-[type].xml.js`. Try using a path like `[type]/[sitemap].js` instead - you'll have access to both `type` and `sitemap` values from the `context.params` object inside `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks, that clarifies a lot.

Comment: @juliomalves do you know if next supports dynamic routes for sitemaps at all? I'm following the docs on dynamic routing, and turning a working `jsx` route into `xml.jsx` gives me a 404.

Comment: Why not use [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to generate the sitemap XML files instead? You can then use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to map the desired paths to the API routes you setup.